# Multiple MailBoxes - Access "drafts" folder of "outlook" email account without using the folder name as a string

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I develop an outlook add-in using Visual studio 2013 and Add-in express v.7.7.4087. 
I have to deal with multiple email accounts (stores). Please see following snapshot and code

[image]

```
private void timerSendFromDraftsFolder_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Stores stores = null; // CC and OL accounts, 
            Outlook.Store store = null;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder rootFolder = null;
            Outlook.Folders rootFolderFolders = null;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder draftsFolder = null;
            Outlook.Items items = null;
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;

            bool itemSent = true;
            bool allMailItemsSent = true;

            try
            {
                if (Helper.IsOnline())
                {
                    Debug.DebugMessage(3, "AddinModule : timerSendFromSaleswingsFolder_Tick : Fired");

                    string version = OutlookApp.Version;
                    if (String.Compare(version, "13") > 0)
                    {
                        stores = Globals.ObjNS.Stores;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= stores.Count; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                store = stores[i];
                                string storeName = store.DisplayName;
                                if (store.ExchangeStoreType != Outlook.OlExchangeStoreType.olExchangePublicFolder)
                                {                                    
                                    rootFolder = store.GetRootFolder();
                                    rootFolderFolders = rootFolder.Folders;
                                    if (rootFolderFolders != null)
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            draftsFolder = rootFolderFolders["drafts"]; // not working for "xxxxxxx@outlook.com" type email accounts
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception )
                                        {
                                            Debug.DebugMessage(3, "AddinModule : timerSendFromSaleswingsFolder_Tick : Excep");
                                            draftsFolder = rootFolderFolders["Drafts (This computer only)"];
                                        }
                                    }
```

I need to access the drafts folder of each mail account, but the email account of “xxxxxxx@**outlook.com**“ shows drafts folder as **"Drafts (This computer only)"** instead of **"drafts"**.

I works fine for me. But I don’t like to introduce this to the production version. Becaues I think this will not work for non-English environments.

1. Can you please suggest me a solution for that
2. In redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), is there a solution for that?

**P.S**

I have used this code in some of my projects

oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);

But it gives the drafts folder of primary mail account. In my code there is no such method for the “store” object here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Store class instead. It allows to get a Folder object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the FolderType argument.

This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

The Redemption library provides the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the [RDOStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm) class.

Comment: It doesn’t provide  GetDefaultFolder() method for my store object. So can I refer to newer assembly using .NET Reflection and call GetDefaultFolder() method? Thank you

Comment: I tried this code. It did not work for me. Please advice me if it make sense https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9507668/reflection.PNG

Answer (score 1):

GetSharedDefaultFolder is the way to go - call Namespace.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve / Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder.

Comment: I tried this code. It did not work for me. Please advice me if it make sense dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9507668/reflection.PNG

Comment: What exactly did not work? Was there an error returned? What is it?